# Optimizing Duplicate node search(Closed list,Open List) on N-Puzzle using A-star

Tags: algorithm, performance, c++11, optimization, a-star

I have coded a program that uses A* algorithm to solve N-Puzzle. The algorithm works perfectly but it seems to be significantly slow compared to all the programs out there using the same algorithm for same problem.
The part I think that is slowing down my code is when new nodes are to be checked for their existence in opened and closed lists.
Essentially what I am doing is checking the entire array of values of the particular node with each node stored in the Closed and the open list.
Here is the code snippet that I believe is causing the slow down.

```
for(auto temp_Node:Neighbours(process))
        {
            auto pred = [temp_Node](Node* item)                         //lambda Expression for 'pred', custom comparator
            {
                bool value=true;
                for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
                    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
                    {
                        if(item->Grid[i][j]!=temp_Node->Grid[i][j])
                        {
                            value=false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                if(item->g!=temp_Node->g)
                    value=false;
                return value;
            };
            if(find_if(begin(closed_list),end(closed_list), pred)==end(closed_list))
            {
                auto open_list_cpy=find_if(begin(open_list),end(open_list), pred);
                if(open_list_cpy==open_list.end())
                {
                    open_list.insert(temp_Node);
                }
```

As you can see I am using lambda expression with find_if to check all the values in each node.

I would like to know if I am missing out something or is there is any other, more efficient way to solve this issue or is this how it is supposed to be done and some other part of my code has the problem?

Comment: Maintain the closed list as a Set, where lookup is O(1) instead of the O(n) your code achieves.

Comment: closed list look up has been reduced to O(log(n)) using the code below, how can it be reduced to O(1)? I don't think it's possible, is it !?

Comment: Any hash table-based set implementation has an amortized O(1) membership test under reasonable assumptions. See for example http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/

Comment: So in this case as I have to find a duplicate `NxN grid` , are you saying to take the entire `Grid` as the Key? as lookup for the grid will be O(1).

Comment: @Gene I tried to implement my `closed_list` as an `unordered_set` but I am unable to come up with a hash function for the 2-dimensional integer array `(Grid)`. Could you suggest a hash function or direct me to a page containing similar information?

Comment: It's impossible to say because you haven't given the declaration for `Grid`.  In general, you'll get more help from SO if you provide small examples that can be compiled and run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of searching through all the nodes sequentially, you may want to keep a `map` or `set` of nodes using the grid for comparison:

```
struct GridLess {
    bool operator()(const Node *a,const Node *b) const
    {
        assert(a);
        assert(b);
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
           for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
           {
               if(a->Grid[i][j]!=b->Grid[i][j])
               {
                   return a->Grid[i][j] < b->Grid[i][j];
               }
           }
        }
        return false;
    }
};


std::set<Node*,GridLess> closed_list;
```

Now you can use

```
if (closed_list.count(temp_Node)==0) {
    // No node in closed_list has the same grid as temp_node
}
```

This reduces the time complexity from O(n) to O(log(n)).

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get it , correct me if I am wrong, here the criteria for checking for duplicates is the address of `Grid` right?
If that's true it won't work for `temp_Node` as it's a completely new node generated by the `neighbor` function thus even if the `Grid` values are same their addresses will be different from the `Nodes` with the same grid in `open_list` or the `closed_list`.

Comment: @phoenixdd   I was thinking of Node::grid as some kind of integer matrix, not as a pointer.   GridLess can be defined however you like though, so if you need to indirect a pointer, you can do that.

Comment: Node::Grid is a 2D integer array exactly as you thought, but I am unable to relate how your code will check for the integer matrix in Neighbours , whether it is same in closed and open lists.
This is the Node declaration if it helps
`struct Node
{
    int x0,y0,g,h,f;
    int Grid[N][N];
    Node* parent=NULL;
    Node(int x=0,int y=0,int G=0,Node* node=NULL)
    {
        x0=x;
        y0=y;
        g=G;
        parent=node;
    }
}`

Comment: @PhoenixDD: I've added how you can do comparisons with raw arrays to my answer.  Note that if you used std::array instead, you could use the built-in comparison operators.

Comment: Will this make it faster than my code? Since using the `closed_list.count(temp_Node)==0` will use the same `for` loop to check for count. Doesn't the complexity of the code remain the same?

Comment: @PhoenixDD: What makes it asymptotically faster is using the `set`, so you have O(log(n)) instead of O(n) comparisons to find a node with a matching grid.

Comment: Oh, it totally escaped my mind that search on a set has O(log(n)) complexity, that is what was bothering me from the beginning.
Thanks a lot, I'll try out using `set` and get back. :)

Comment: The use of set has drastically improved the solve time, from ~195 seconds to ~13 seconds for the same instance of the puzzle, though it's still way longer than most of the other programs out there,
Could you suggest any more changes?
I am using Node::f as comparison on `open_list` which is type `multiset` so that I won't have to search to pick up the optimum Node, should I change the comparison same as the `closed_list` would that be faster? 
Any other help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @PhoenixDD: I suspect that using a set for the closed_list would help as well, but the best thing to do is try.

Comment: I'll definitely give it a try, also I create an NxN array each time a Node is created, is there any faster replacement for this? like not storing the Puzzle state? or changing the way I save the puzzle state in each Node?

Comment: @PhoenixDD: For large puzzles,  you might get a benefit from storing the states in a tree, where a node represents all the states that have the first m positions at certain values, where m is the node depth.  Each node in the state tree would then just need to store the value of one tile.  Finding a matching state would just involve following the proper branch of the tree.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you mean, could you provide an example? maybe by taking instances of N puzzle?

Comment: I get it now Thank you!

Comment: @PhoenixDD: unordered_set isn't always faster.  In your case, the hash time increases with N.

Comment: I was wondering that since `set` uses the same `GridLess` for comparison which has worst case of O(n) to compute it's result so does the hash function they both take same time to compute the comparison and the lookup time in `unordered_set` is O(1) rather than O(log n) in `set` shouldn't using hash table be faster in this case?

Comment: @PhoenixDD: The time is more complex than that.  The `n` for hashing is the number of grid cells in the puzzle, whereas the `n` for lookup is the number of states.